# error C1189: #error : Please define your platform

Tags: c++

I have this err when I build on visual studio ultimate2010, can you have me fix this error, thanks so much!

> Error 1   error C1189: #error :  Please define your
>   platform. d:\dzz\src\flexengine\fxcore\platform.h 28  1   battleserver

```
#pragma once

// 平台定义
#if defined __APPLE__
#include "AvailabilityMacros.h"
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
    #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        /* if compiling for iPhone */
        #define PLATFORM_IPHONE     1
    #else
        #define PLATFORM_MACOSX     1
    #endif
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define PLATFORM_IPHONE     1
#elif ANDROID
#define PLATFORM_ANDROID    1
#elif _WINDOWS
#define PLATFORM_WINDOWS    1
#elif (defined(__linux__))
#define PLATFORM_LINUX      1
#elif (defined(unix))
#define PLATFORM_UNIX       1
#else
#error Please define your platform.
#endif

// 64位检测
 #if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(__LP64__) || defined(__POWERPC64__) || defined( _WIN64 )
    #define PLATFORM_64     1
#elif defined(__i386__) || defined(_M_IX86) || defined(_M_PPC) || defined(__LP32__) || defined(__POWERPC__) || IPHONE || ANDROID
    #define PLATFORM_32     1
#else
    #define PLATFORM_32     1
    // #error Please define your platform.
#endif

// 是否支持异常
#if PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#define PLATFORM_EXCEPTIONS     1
#else
#define PLATFORM_EXCEPTIONS     0
#endif


// Platform specific include.
#if PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    #include "platform_windows.h"
#elif PLATFORM_IPHONE
    #include "platform_iphone.h"
#elif PLATFORM_MACOSX
    #include "platform_macosx.h"
#elif PLATFORM_ANDROID
    #include "platform_android.h"
#elif PLATFORM_LINUX
    #include "platform_linux.h"
#else
    #error Unknown platform.
#endif
```

Comment: It seems like adding `_WINDOWS` to the macros in your project settings could do it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this `platform.h` attempts to use pre-defined macros to detect the target platform. However, it tries to use `_WINDOWS` macro to detect windows, which is apparently a pre-processor macro supported by the [Watcom compiler](http://www.ousob.com/ng/wcppug/ng91a37.php).

Your options:

- Since the library that you use apparently only supports the watcom compiler on windows, you could use that instead of visual studio. If you choose to use VS, there may be other issues down the line that need to be fixed to support it besides this one.
- You could work around the issue by defining the macro yourself.
- You could fix the header to work with visual studio by replacing `#elif _WINDOWS` with `#elif _WIN32`. See [macros pre-defined by visual studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

I recommend going with the latter approach, however porting the library to VS may (or may not) involve a non-trivial amount of work.